# Porting Tensor flow lite micro to non supported platform

Tags: tensorflow-lite

There is no existing port for the processor I am using (Arm R4f).
How difficult is it to create a custom port myself?

If the tensorflow lite micro platform is a C++ library, why is a dedicated port necessary in the first place?

Thanks